# How to open a dialog box without clicking

Tags: javascript

hello I would like to be able to display a personalized dialog box

I don't want to use the javascript alert box

I don't want this box to be able to open with a click

I have a code but when I run it in codpen nothing is displayed

it must surely be bad it would be nice to give me an example

```
<head>
   .BoxAlert {
          /* margin-top: -200px;*/
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 10;
          left: 10%;
          background-color: #8695b7;
          color: #090908;
          height: 150px;
          width: 320px;
          font-size: 20px;
        }

        .BoxAlert:before {
          content: "";
          position: fixed;
          z-index: -10;
          display: block;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          right: 0;
          background: #0007;
        }

        .BoxAlert>div {
          border: 0.25em solid black;
          border-radius: 0.25em;
          padding: 0.25em;
          background: #fff;
        }
  
</head>
<body>


<script src="script.js">

                    function openBoxAlert() {
                      let m;
                      m = "<div style ='text-align: center;'>\ Vous êtes  <br> ";
                      m += "Pour trouver le point Relais";
                      m += "<br><span style='  color: red; font-weight: bold;'>quelques secondes</span>";
                      m += "<br>";                   
                      m += "</div>";
 }
openBoxAlert();



</script>


</body>
```

Comment: I think you need to wrap your css in a `<style`> tag. You're creating a variable, `m`, that contains a string, but you don't do anything with it. Are you looking to append it to the document body?

Comment: Why is javascript even part of the process in this case?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just want a dialog box that can open in a condition, if the condition is true the dialog box opens on its own

Comment: actually this is what i want
https://zupimages.net/up/23/08/ejy4.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can create elements with `document.createElement`. Append them to the `<body>` so that they are actually shown. (Additionally, your CSS should go into a separate file or in a `<style>` element.)

```js
function openBoxAlert() {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.textAlign = 'center';
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.style.color = 'red';
  span.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  span.textContent = 'quelques secondes';
  div.append("Vous êtes  ", document.createElement('br'), 
    "Pour trouver le point Relais", document.createElement('br'), 
    span, document.createElement('br'));
  document.body.append(div);
}
openBoxAlert();
```

```css
.BoxAlert{position:absolute;z-index:10;left:10%;background-color:#8695b7;color:#090908;height:150px;width:320px;font-size:20px}.BoxAlert:before{content:"";position:fixed;z-index:-10;display:block;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;background:#0007}.BoxAlert>div{border:.25em solid #000;border-radius:.25em;padding:.25em;background:#fff}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code
but the css is not taken into account

Comment: @ariane Put the CSS between `<style>` tags: `<style>/*CSS here*/</style>`

Comment: I give you the codepen https://codepen.io/flexi2202/pen/rNZeQBw

Comment: @ariane What's the issue?

Comment: I only have text that is displayed I want the text to be displayed in a dialog box that I can close

Comment: actually this is what i want
https://zupimages.net/up/23/08/ejy4.jpg